# How to use preg_split for br tag

Tags: php, parsing

The following code not parsing `<br>` tag effect

```
$html="test<br>end";

preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

How to use it for line break?

Edit:

Required result is:

```
0 => 'test', 1 => 'end'
```

Comment: That code example will give you an array with 3 strings. What did you expect to get? NB: For input strings with more tags, you will want to use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`.

Comment: @trincot I want to break text but above not working. Also `(.*?)` is not effective here

Comment: I've copied and run your code and it gives me `array (  0 => 'test',  1 => 'br',  2 => 'end')`. Please elaborate why this is not what you want.

Comment: @ob-ivan I want to parse `<br>` tag for line break. This should not be in array

Comment: what do you mean by parse here?? elaborate your requirement please with examples

Comment: If that is the required result, why are you using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag?  Is your actual input string, a larger html string? regex is not to be used to parse html.

Comment: `preg_split('/<(br)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: Very interesting this question got an upvote.

Comment: Possibly you wanted to specify `u` (lower case) at the end of your regex, not `U` which has a totally different meaning (and a very confusing one -- to be avoided!) and @mickmackusa .... #metoo :-)

Comment: @trincot I'm not sure I agree with you.  The `U` is sensibly used (I kind of don't want to use _sensibly_ here) because `*` is greedy, the `U` forces laziness.  Would I do it?  No, I wouldn't.

Comment: @mickmackusa, exactly, I would not do it either, unless I want to confuse readers of the code. ;-)

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Please improve this question so that its status can move toward resolution.

Comment: Can we move this question toward a resolution?

Comment: @mickmackusa I cannot get answers

Comment: If you have not posted your actual code, please copy-paste it into your question so that we know exactly what you are trying to do and exactly what the actual string is.

Answer (score 1):

No regex is necessary for your sample input string.

```
$html="test<br>end";
var_export(explode('<br>',$html));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'test',
  1 => 'end',
)
```

---

If you want to replace: use `str_replace()`.

```
$html="test<br>end";
var_export(str_replace('<br>',"\n",$html));
```

Output:

```
'test
end'
```

---

If you insist on using `preg_split()`, then this is my suggetion:

```
$html="test<br>end";
var_export(preg_split('/<[^>]*>/',$html));
```

The negated character class runs faster than the `.` (any non-newline character).  Keep in mind, this will match all tags in your string (and anything else that is between `<` and `>`).

...

If we are only targeting `<br>` and `<br />` then the pattern can be: `~<br(?: /)?>~`.  But now I am scrambling to speculate what the problem is because vital questions have not been answered.

Comment: Question is How to use `preg_split` for br tag, not using `explode()`

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Yes, I read your question.  I am offering you better advice than you are asking for.  This is not a mistake.  I understand `preg_split()` very well and I actually love to use the function.  Your task does not call for its use.

Comment: Since explicitly said by OP it's better to point to `br` tags in your regex specifically: `~<br\s*/?>~`

Comment: @revo fair enough... I'm starting to wonder if there is a `<br>` at all.  Maybe there is an `\n` and the OP doesn't know it.

Comment: Seems that's the case and OP's not able to clarify. Cast a closing vote.

Comment: @revo Let's close this thing... Please vote as Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to also split by any other tag, and your text might contain non-Latin characters, I would suggest:

- using the unicode modifier (lower case `u`) so this works correctly for multibyte (non-ASCII) characters.
- I personally find the use of the upper case `U` only leading to misunderstandings. Leave it out and at the same time change `(.*)` to `(.*?)` to get the same effect.
- As you don't want to see `<br>` in your resulting array, you need to remove the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag, which actually forces that `<br>` into the results.

So applying all that, we get:

```
$html="test<br>end";

$result = preg_split('/<(.*?)>/u', $html);

print_r($result); // Array( [0] => "test", [1] => "end" )
```

Comment: @Muhammad `preg_split()` is wasteful for this task, as is a capture group.

Comment: If only matching `<br>` then the unicode flag is no use.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb29c40b81262d85184685dc1c702cea67678569  (I don't think the pattern modifier was a capitalization typo)

Comment: I need line break effect in string, your code also not doing this.

Comment: Which line break, and which effect? Your question says you want `0 => 'test', 1 => 'end'`: I don't see any line break... Be also aware that a browser suppresses line breaks when you display the result without further `pre`-CSS styling in effect.

Comment: Let's close this thing... Please vote as Unclear what you are asking.